# php upload not working to get .vcf file type

Tags: php, types, upload, mime

Hello I cannot get this to work and am looking for some help.

Here is my current code:

```
$accepted_file_mime_types = array('image/gif','image/jpg','image/jpeg','image/png','application/pdf','application/zip','application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document','application/msword','text/plain','audio/wav','audio/mp3','audio/mp4');
$file_extension = strtolower(strrchr($_FILES["userpro_file"]["name"], "."));

if( !in_array($file_extension, array( '.gif','.jpg','.jpeg','.png','.pdf','.txt','.zip','.doc','.docx','.wav','.mp3','.mp4'  )  ) || !in_array($fileinfo,$accepted_file_mime_types) ){
 // .. Do stuff
}
```

here is the code that I have tried, however still gives me the error of invalid file type:

```
$accepted_file_mime_types = array('image/gif','image/jpg','image/jpeg','image/png','application/pdf','application/zip','application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document','application/msword','text/plain','audio/wav','audio/mp3','audio/mp4', 'text/x-vcard');
$file_extension = strtolower(strrchr($_FILES["userpro_file"]["name"], "."));
if( !in_array($file_extension, array( '.gif','.jpg','.jpeg','.png','.pdf','.txt','.zip','.doc','.docx','.wav','.mp3','.mp4','.vcf'  )  ) || !in_array($fileinfo,$accepted_file_mime_types) ){
    // do stuff
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

vCard files have mimetypes of

```
text/vcard
```

You'd need to add that as one of the accepted_file_mime_types. If it's not that, it could be any of the following mimetypes which are now [deprecated](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VCard).

```
text/x-vcard
text/directory;profile=vCard
text/directory
```

*Edit* - if it still does not work, you will need to output the mimetype when you upload the file to see what needs to be accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Try a MIME type of `text/vcard`. `text/x-vcard` is deprecated.

Comment: the mime type that works for me is vcard